# Como mostrar un contenido en mi web dependiendo de la resolución con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

Muy buenas amigos, tengo cierto problema con un requerimiento en un proyecto, este consiste en poder mostrar cierto contenido en base a la resolución de la pantalla del usuario, verán, tengo que mostrar ciertos pdf, pero por parte del usuario este puede tener diferentes resoluciones, la cual con un script se pudo demostrar que algunos tienen pantallas de 800x600, esto se presenta en un problema puesto que el visor es muy personalizado y no soporta estas resoluciones, por lo que se tiene que optar por el cambio de visor, para esto utilizo la propiedades `screen.width` y `screen.height` para esto uso el siguiente código:

```
if(screen.width <= 1000){
  $('#visor_pref').hide();
  $('#visor_prof').show();
}

if(sreen.width > 1000){
  $('#visor_pref').show();
  $('#visor_prof').hide();
}
```

El problema es que, aunque este en oculto los dos visores hacen la consulta al pdf, lo cual es una carga para la conexión, esto no puede ser, ¿¿¿¿cómo puedo hacer para mostrar un visor u otro sin hacer el uso de la descarga de los meta datos de los pdf???? Ósea que al hacer uso de un visor u otro solo se descargue los meta datos de un solo visor y no de los dos

Otro es como puedo bloquear el click derecho sobre un `<embed type=”application/pdf”>` ya que una de la intención es no poder permitir el descargar los archivos que se muestren

Comment: Muestra más código, probablemente lo único que necesitas es activar el visor de acuerdo al ancho de la pantalla en lugar de cargar siempre ambos.

Comment: el visor que ulizo es este https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js, alli se encuentra el visor predefinido que ellos poseen y es el que utilizo, del resto solo le paso la url de mi pdf para cargarlo

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que usas para mostrar el PDF, incluye las dos formas.